# How to pull attachments from Google Glass item?

Tags: node.js, google-glass, google-mirror-api

I created NodeJS server that communicate with Google Glass, I want to know how to pull attachment from item, below you can see the item with attachments:
[image]

Note: in my project I already have:
*Send item item to glass(contact, card, location, etc..)
*Subscription to timeline collection
*Contact with callback to let Glass user share content  - for more info Visit [How to add another option to the share functionality of Google Glass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462202/how-to-add-another-option-to-the-share-functionality-of-google-glass/)

Do I need to use the selfLink to pull the attachment? if yes then how I can execute HTTP request for the selfLink while including the token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `selfLink` refers to the URL of the timelineItem itself. You want to look at the `attachments` attribute of the object. It might look something like this:

```
{ "kind": "mirror#timelineItem",
  "id": "da61598c-2890-4852-2123-031011dfa004",
  ...
  "attachments": [
    "id": ...
    "contentType": "image/jpeg".
    "contentUrl": "https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline/da61598c-2890-4852-2123-031011dfa004/attachments/ps:605507433604363824",
    "isProcessingContent": false
  ]
}
```

You should check to make sure `isProcessingContent` is false before you try to fetch it, otherwise the fetch will fail. This is usually pretty quick for images, but can take longer for video.

See more at https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/attachments

To fetch it, you can issue an HTTPS request to that URL with an `Authorization` header with a value of `Bearer auth_token` (replacing auth_token with the actual value of the auth token).

To make the request itself, you'll probably want to use the `http.request()` method. So something like this (untested) might work:

```
var item = {the item you got sent above};
var attachment = item.attachments[0];
if( !attachment.isProcessingContent ){
  var contentUrl = url.parse( attachment.contentUrl );
  var options = {
    "hostname": contentUrl.hostname,
    "path": contentUrl.path,
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": 'Bearer '+authToken;
    }
  }
  https.request( options, function(res){
    // Get the image from the res object
  });
}
```

See the documentation for [URL.parse](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) and [HTTPS.request](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) for details.

Comment: Thank you @Prisoner for the great answer, I looked into the attachment and found attachment id, then I needed to run mirror.timeline.attachments.get(params) ... while the params include the attachment id and the item id that the attachment referred to.